# How to get a solid line between each row in a table?

Tags: html, css

Html is not my specialty :)

I have an Html table and I want to have a solid line between each row.  I've done it by defining a `border-bottom` on each `<td>` tag, like so:

```
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0066ff;">[content]</td>
```

But it comes out with a one-pixel gap in the line, as seen below:

[image]

I tried putting the `border-bottom` in the `<tr>` tag, but that didn't work at all.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: did you try `border` to parent `<tr>` ?

Comment: Trying setting `border-spacing` A [useful article](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the CSS attribute `border-collapse` and set it to `collapse`:

```css
table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0066ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give cellspacing 0 to the table

```
<table cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px;">sdfa</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px;">asfsaf</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dnappj7/)